# polyfit with multi-dimensional x coordinate

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, polynomials, numpy-ufunc

Suppose that I have a (400,10) array called `x` and a (400,10) array called `y`. Is that possible to do a polyfit of each row in `y` to the corresponding row in `x` **without iteration**? If with `for` loop it will be something like

```
import numpy as np

coe = np.zeros((400,3))    
for i in np.arange(y.shape[0]): 
    coe[i,:] = np.polyfit(x[i,:], y[i,:], 2)
```

Because the 400 rows in `x` is totally different, I cannot just apply np.polyfit with the same `x` coordinate to a multi-dimensional array `y`.

Comment: sorry for my typing mistake. It is numpy not bumpy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a comprehension?

`coe = [tuple(np.polyfit(x[i,:], y[i,:], 2)) for i in range(400)]`

- The range(400) emits the values 0 to 399 into i
- For each i, you compute the polyfit for x[i,:] vs y[i,:].  I believe the results are a tuple (p, v)
- The resulting list-of-tuples is assigned to coe

At the innermost levels, this is an iteration - but in Python 3, such comprehensions are optimized for performance at the C level, so you will probably see a nice performance boost doing it this way over using a for: loop.